# AutoHotKey: Remap Alt, Ctrl, and Alt+Ctrl

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to use AutoHotKey to remap:

```
RAlt::Volume_Down
RCtrl::Volume_Up
RAlt & RCtrl::SendInput {Volume_Mute}
```

While Vol up works fine with the script as above, vol down is non-repeating & mute only works if the buttons are pressed as Alt,Ctrl (not Ctrl,Alt). I understand why, I just haven't been able to come up with a solution. I can map *either* volume up/down *or* mute - but if I try to do both, the behavior is always finicky. I think what I need is something to the effect of:

```
if GetKeyState("RAlt") and GetKeyState("RCtrl")
{
    SendInput {Volume_Mute}
}
else if GetKeyState("RAlt")
{
    SendInput {Volume_Down}
}
else if GetKeyState("RCtrl")
{
    SendInput {Volume_Up}
}
```

But this just runs & terminates. Is there a way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that `RAlt & RCtrl::SendInput {Volume_Mute}` turns `RAlt` into a "prefix key" and according to the Hotkeys section of Autohotkey help "*The prefix key loses its native function*".

Try this instead:

```
RAlt::Volume_Down
RCtrl::Volume_Up

#if GetKeyState("RAlt", "P")
RCtrl::Volume_Mute

#if GetKeyState("RCtrl", "P")
RAlt::Volume_Mute
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much :D